# java looping an method with an array with another arrays values

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I have two arrays:

- One with all the high temperatures for each day of 2015.
- One with the number of days in each month (for example the first index is 31 then 28 and so on).

I need to make a method that finds the average high temperature for a month and then in main, i need to write a loop that loops the method over and over getting each months average and printing them.

Here is my attempt for the method

```
public static double monthaverage(int[] a, int [] b, int c) {
    int j=b[c];
    int total = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <j; i++)
            total += a[i];
            double average = (double)total/ (double) j;

    return average; 
}
```

And, my attempt for the loop and data in main

```
    int[] tmax = {32, 38, 34, 35, 41, 17, 25, 17, 29, 24, 26, 33, 31, 24, 
                  29, 38, 20, 49, 49, 36, 31, 38, 35, 32, 37, 20, 17, 26, 
                  30, 32, 22, 26, 12, 20, 35, 34, 19, 28, 22, 15, 30, 23, 
                  20, 17, 16, 19, 21, 21, 32, 33, 19, 34, 35, 31, 19, 34, 
                  21, 27, 27, 30, 36, 32, 46, 39, 23, 38, 40, 44, 47, 56, 
                  41, 39, 38, 36, 45, 44, 28, 32, 34, 36, 35, 34, 39, 42, 
                  49, 49, 41, 41, 40, 48, 45, 46, 66, 49, 48, 41, 47, 42, 
                  35, 43, 54, 68, 66, 70, 65, 55, 67, 55, 57, 48, 63, 60, 
                  53, 54, 55, 56, 58, 63, 57, 60, 55, 54, 62, 76, 75, 72, 
                  84, 58, 59, 83, 68, 82, 64, 68, 70, 63, 74, 61, 65, 67, 
                  69, 67, 65, 83, 84, 91, 79, 80, 77, 84, 73, 51, 50, 61, 
                  60, 58, 73, 67, 65, 68, 81, 86, 80, 85, 78, 61, 61, 75, 
                  72, 80, 69, 72, 72, 67, 82, 78, 67, 70, 59, 69, 75, 68, 
                  78, 80, 71, 82, 82, 76, 84, 72, 84, 87, 90, 78, 76, 82, 
                  76, 74, 70, 81, 84, 70, 82, 78, 76, 67, 67, 77, 83, 88, 
                  86, 86, 86, 81, 81, 80, 82, 80, 76, 80, 77, 77, 67, 80, 
                  77, 80, 85, 85, 89, 86, 83, 75, 73, 78, 70, 79, 75, 80, 
                  79, 77, 75, 81, 86, 80, 84, 86, 72, 78, 82, 92, 89, 86, 
                  78, 73, 74, 62, 73, 83, 85, 82, 83, 75, 72, 69, 65, 74, 
                  74, 63, 63, 67, 74, 75, 69, 62, 55, 58, 58, 61, 69, 67, 
                  63, 59, 56, 68, 70, 62, 68, 57, 61, 57, 46, 48, 66, 58, 
                  65, 54, 47, 62, 54, 52, 59, 73, 58, 51, 58, 64, 64, 64, 
                  68, 69, 65, 53, 58, 53, 47, 53, 60, 46, 53, 54, 47, 47, 
                  53, 59, 46, 42, 42, 42, 41, 51, 61, 57, 41, 32, 38, 44, 
                  45, 47, 51, 51, 57, 39, 45, 53, 48, 57, 47, 48, 56, 42, 
                  50, 46, 40, 38, 47, 49, 47, 51, 62, 51, 43, 34, 23, 28, 
                  44};
      int [] monthlength= {31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
      for (int i = 0; i <12; i++){
        average= monthaverage(tmax, monthlength, c);
        System.out.println("Average: test " + average);
        c++;
    }
```

Comment: In your bottom `for` the variable `c` should be `i` ?

Comment: Fixed layout to be more readable

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to get the average temperature. Please note that I have added SampleTemperature class to with main method.

```
public class SampleTemperature {
public static double monthaverage(int[] a, int[] b, int c) {
    int j = b[c];
    int total = 0;
    int totalDays=0;
    for (int numOfMonth=0;(numOfMonth<c);numOfMonth++) {
        totalDays+=b[numOfMonth];
    }
    //System.out.println(c+"Start Date:"+totalDays+" Number of days"+j);
    int startdate=totalDays;
    for (int i = startdate; i < startdate+j; i++)
        total += a[i];
    double average = (double) total / (double) j;

    return average;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] tmax = { 32, 38, 34, 35, 41, 17, 25, 17, 29, 24, 26, 33, 31, 24, 29, 38, 20, 49, 49, 36, 31, 38, 35, 32,
            37, 20, 17, 26, 30, 32, 22, 26, 12, 20, 35, 34, 19, 28, 22, 15, 30, 23, 20, 17, 16, 19, 21, 21, 32, 33,
            19, 34, 35, 31, 19, 34, 21, 27, 27, 30, 36, 32, 46, 39, 23, 38, 40, 44, 47, 56, 41, 39, 38, 36, 45, 44,
            28, 32, 34, 36, 35, 34, 39, 42, 49, 49, 41, 41, 40, 48, 45, 46, 66, 49, 48, 41, 47, 42, 35, 43, 54, 68,
            66, 70, 65, 55, 67, 55, 57, 48, 63, 60, 53, 54, 55, 56, 58, 63, 57, 60, 55, 54, 62, 76, 75, 72, 84, 58,
            59, 83, 68, 82, 64, 68, 70, 63, 74, 61, 65, 67, 69, 67, 65, 83, 84, 91, 79, 80, 77, 84, 73, 51, 50, 61,
            60, 58, 73, 67, 65, 68, 81, 86, 80, 85, 78, 61, 61, 75, 72, 80, 69, 72, 72, 67, 82, 78, 67, 70, 59, 69,
            75, 68, 78, 80, 71, 82, 82, 76, 84, 72, 84, 87, 90, 78, 76, 82, 76, 74, 70, 81, 84, 70, 82, 78, 76, 67,
            67, 77, 83, 88, 86, 86, 86, 81, 81, 80, 82, 80, 76, 80, 77, 77, 67, 80, 77, 80, 85, 85, 89, 86, 83, 75,
            73, 78, 70, 79, 75, 80, 79, 77, 75, 81, 86, 80, 84, 86, 72, 78, 82, 92, 89, 86, 78, 73, 74, 62, 73, 83,
            85, 82, 83, 75, 72, 69, 65, 74, 74, 63, 63, 67, 74, 75, 69, 62, 55, 58, 58, 61, 69, 67, 63, 59, 56, 68,
            70, 62, 68, 57, 61, 57, 46, 48, 66, 58, 65, 54, 47, 62, 54, 52, 59, 73, 58, 51, 58, 64, 64, 64, 68, 69,
            65, 53, 58, 53, 47, 53, 60, 46, 53, 54, 47, 47, 53, 59, 46, 42, 42, 42, 41, 51, 61, 57, 41, 32, 38, 44,
            45, 47, 51, 51, 57, 39, 45, 53, 48, 57, 47, 48, 56, 42, 50, 46, 40, 38, 47, 49, 47, 51, 62, 51, 43, 34,
            23, 28, 44 };
    int[] monthlength = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };
    for (int i = 0; i < monthlength.length; i++) {
        double average = monthaverage(tmax, monthlength, i);
        System.out.println("Average: test " + average);
    }
}
}
```

**Updated** according to the comment

Comment: this works but I still have my issue with the loop in main that does not go to the next month, keeps printing out the same number. I want it to use the method find the average of all days in the tmax array of the given month in the monthlength array and then move on to February in and use the next 28  values in tmax in the method for the average and the loop in main prints out that and continues looping through each month using the average method. hopefully that helps explain what i am trying to do and is not complete nonsense

Comment: Sorry I did not check your logic I thought it's correct check the updated answer.

Comment: Have you checked with the updated answer ? If it's resolve your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my version, it's essentially the same idea as @Coder with a few extra print outs / few extra named variables for following along easier.

First, You'll notice the main() method is essentially the same. It loops over each month in the year (via index 0-11, respectively) and prints out the average temp. The other println call in the loop is just a visual to separate the output text.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; ++i) {
        System.out.println(new String(new char[80]).replace("\0", "-"));
        System.out.println("Average: test " + monthAverage(i));
    }
}
```

Second, you'll notice the monthAverage() method is quite large at first sight, but it can be reduced after the fact by quite a lot - most of the bloat comes from proper naming of variables to better help illustrate what each respective one is used for. Also note: camelCase is good convention to follow in java.

```
public static double monthAverage(int monthIndex) {
    if (monthIndex < 0 || monthIndex > 11)
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("month index out of range.");
    double result = 0L;
    int startOffset = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < monthIndex; ++i)
        startOffset += monthLength[i];
    int len = monthLength[monthIndex];
    int endOffset = startOffset + len;
    System.out.printf("Day #'s: start=%03d, end=%03d, elapsed=%d, local month=%s",
            startOffset, endOffset, len, new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths()[monthIndex]);
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = startOffset; i < endOffset; ++i) {
        double dayTemp = (double) tmax[i];
        result += dayTemp;
    }
    return (result / len);
}
```

monthAverage() starts off by making sure the index is a correct one to use. then the start/end days are computed. and finally the average for the month is taken and returned.

Altogether it looks like this:

```
import java.text.DateFormatSymbols;

public class App {
    public static final int[] tmax = { 32, 38, 34, 35, 41, 17, 25, 17, 29, 24, 26, 33, 31, 24, 29, 38, 20, 49, 49, 36,
            31, 38, 35, 32, 37, 20, 17, 26, 30, 32, 22, 26, 12, 20, 35, 34, 19, 28, 22, 15, 30, 23, 20, 17, 16, 19, 21,
            21, 32, 33, 19, 34, 35, 31, 19, 34, 21, 27, 27, 30, 36, 32, 46, 39, 23, 38, 40, 44, 47, 56, 41, 39, 38, 36,
            45, 44, 28, 32, 34, 36, 35, 34, 39, 42, 49, 49, 41, 41, 40, 48, 45, 46, 66, 49, 48, 41, 47, 42, 35, 43, 54,
            68, 66, 70, 65, 55, 67, 55, 57, 48, 63, 60, 53, 54, 55, 56, 58, 63, 57, 60, 55, 54, 62, 76, 75, 72, 84, 58,
            59, 83, 68, 82, 64, 68, 70, 63, 74, 61, 65, 67, 69, 67, 65, 83, 84, 91, 79, 80, 77, 84, 73, 51, 50, 61, 60,
            58, 73, 67, 65, 68, 81, 86, 80, 85, 78, 61, 61, 75, 72, 80, 69, 72, 72, 67, 82, 78, 67, 70, 59, 69, 75, 68,
            78, 80, 71, 82, 82, 76, 84, 72, 84, 87, 90, 78, 76, 82, 76, 74, 70, 81, 84, 70, 82, 78, 76, 67, 67, 77, 83,
            88, 86, 86, 86, 81, 81, 80, 82, 80, 76, 80, 77, 77, 67, 80, 77, 80, 85, 85, 89, 86, 83, 75, 73, 78, 70, 79,
            75, 80, 79, 77, 75, 81, 86, 80, 84, 86, 72, 78, 82, 92, 89, 86, 78, 73, 74, 62, 73, 83, 85, 82, 83, 75, 72,
            69, 65, 74, 74, 63, 63, 67, 74, 75, 69, 62, 55, 58, 58, 61, 69, 67, 63, 59, 56, 68, 70, 62, 68, 57, 61, 57,
            46, 48, 66, 58, 65, 54, 47, 62, 54, 52, 59, 73, 58, 51, 58, 64, 64, 64, 68, 69, 65, 53, 58, 53, 47, 53, 60,
            46, 53, 54, 47, 47, 53, 59, 46, 42, 42, 42, 41, 51, 61, 57, 41, 32, 38, 44, 45, 47, 51, 51, 57, 39, 45, 53,
            48, 57, 47, 48, 56, 42, 50, 46, 40, 38, 47, 49, 47, 51, 62, 51, 43, 34, 23, 28, 44 };
    public static final int[] monthLength = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; ++i) {
            System.out.println(new String(new char[80]).replace("\0", "-"));
            System.out.println("Average: test " + monthAverage(i));
        }
    }

    /**
     * monthAverage method
     * 
     * @param monthIndex
     *            The given month average to compute (e.g. 0 = jan. 11 = dec.)
     * @return the average temp
     */
    public static double monthAverage(int monthIndex) {
        if (monthIndex < 0 || monthIndex > 11)
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("month index out of range.");
        double result = 0L;
        int startOffset = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < monthIndex; ++i)
            startOffset += monthLength[i];
        int len = monthLength[monthIndex];
        int endOffset = startOffset + len;
        System.out.printf("Day #'s: start=%03d, end=%03d, elapsed=%d, local month=%s",
                startOffset, endOffset, len, new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths()[monthIndex]);
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = startOffset; i < endOffset; ++i) {
            double dayTemp = (double) tmax[i];
            result += dayTemp;
        }
        return (result / len);
    }
}
```

Here's my output:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Day #'s: start=000, end=031, elapsed=31, local month=January
30.548387096774192
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Day #'s: start=031, end=059, elapsed=28, local month=February
24.642857142857142
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Day #'s: start=059, end=090, elapsed=31, local month=March
39.41935483870968
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Day #'s: start=090, end=120, elapsed=30, local month=April
54.86666666666667
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Day #'s: start=120, end=151, elapsed=31, local month=May
71.35483870967742
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Day #'s: start=151, end=181, elapsed=30, local month=June
69.73333333333333
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Day #'s: start=181, end=212, elapsed=31, local month=July
78.54838709677419
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Day #'s: start=212, end=243, elapsed=31, local month=August
79.35483870967742
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Day #'s: start=243, end=273, elapsed=30, local month=September
76.06666666666666
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Day #'s: start=273, end=304, elapsed=31, local month=October
59.483870967741936
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Day #'s: start=304, end=334, elapsed=30, local month=November
53.0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Day #'s: start=334, end=365, elapsed=31, local month=December
45.83870967741935
```

Hope that helps, let me know if there's anything I left out/needs explaining/isn't correct, cheers.